# Parse Twitter Timeline json Windows Phone

Tags: json, twitter, windows-phone

I'm trying  to parse Twitter timeline, but I have an error: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

Here is code:

```
 private void GetUserTimeLine(string userName)
    {
        WebClient wcTwitterTimeline = new WebClient();
        wcTwitterTimeline.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wcTwitterTimeline_DownloadStringCompleted);
        wcTwitterTimeline.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=" + userName));
    }

    void wcTwitterTimeline_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


            List<RootObject> tweets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(e.Result);
            this.listboxMyTimeline.ItemsSource = tweets;

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                listboxMyTimeline.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                txtBoxNewTweet.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                btnPostTweet.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            });
        }
```

Error begins here:

```
List<RootObject> tweets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(e.Result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 Not Found might be because you're URL scheme is http and should be https. After you resolve this, your next error might be 401 Unauthorized because Twitter API v1.1 requires OAuth authentication. You might want to check out the [Twitter API FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq) and referenced docs for more details.